# Parallax Scrolling like old school snes games using Sprite kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

Hi I'm using this code to scroll my tile map, what would be the best way to implement parallax scrolling? Ive figured out a way, but it doesn't work very well. :(

```
- (void)setViewpointCenter:(CGPoint)position {
NSInteger x = MAX(position.x, self.size.width / 2);
NSInteger y = MAX(position.y, self.size.height / 2);

x = MIN(x, (self.map.mapSize.width * self.map.tileSize.width) - self.size.width / 2);
y = MIN(y, (self.map.mapSize.height * self.map.tileSize.height) - self.size.height / 2);

CGPoint actualPosition = CGPointMake(x, y);
CGPoint centerOfView = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);

CGPoint viewPoint = CGPointSubtract(centerOfView, actualPosition);
self.map.position = viewPoint;
}
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Roll your background map a fixed percentage of the foreground sprites. Typically this is only done in the axis most movement happens in (eg horizontal for side-scrollers and vertical for up-scrollers).

The following pseudo-code, assuming a side-scroller where you start at the bottom left of the map, this bottom left is (0,0) and axes increase as you move up/right

```
backgroundPercent = 80
background_x = foreground_x * backgroundPercent / 100
backgroup_y = foreground_y
```

Using the above, your background map only needs to be 80% as wide as the foreground